# Trying to exclude text from flushright

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm working on a resume here in LaTex and having some difficulties alligning some text. Please find the code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch} % font
\pagestyle{empty} % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram} % column layout
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx} % figures
\usepackage{url} % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage{multicol} % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist} % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\upshape\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

 \newcommand{\cventry}[3]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{\hspace{0.5cm}}r@{}}%@{\extracolsep{1cm}}
{\bfseries #1} & {#2} \\%
{#3} &\\%
\end{tabularx}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newenvironment{Objective}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} Objective}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}
    \footnotesize{ \href{https://www.google.be/}{xxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyy}} \\
    \scriptsize{xyyyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com}  \\
    \scriptsize{+xx yyy xx xx xx} \\
    \scriptsize{xx years} \\
    \SmallSep
    \scriptsize{WallStreet 10}  \\
    \scriptsize{New York} \\ 
    \scriptsize{USA} \\
    \Sep
    \textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} \raggedright{Languages}} \\
    \begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item \scriptsize{Spanish}
    \item \scriptsize{English}
    \item \scriptsize{French} \\ \tiny{(Elementary proficiency)}
    \end{compactitem}

\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

So everything is placed in this flushright tag, but I want to exclude the 'languages' title from this flush , but wasn't able to do so yet.

Also, ideally, I would like to indent the bullet points of those items a bit further to the right, so it matches the same indentation as the name that is directly under the picture.

Does anybody know how to do that?
*current situation:
[image]

*what I would like to achieve:
[image]

If I simply remove the flushright from those last few lines, it messes up everything and text gets placed over the picture etc.

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Try `\textbf{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{Languages}}\hfill~\\`.

I also take liberty and correct your code:

- `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize` and similar font sizes are switches, not a environments. I correct all their wrong use
- I changed your definition of `\cventry`
- I added text for the second column (copied from my answer on the your previous question), where you can see advantages of of use of the modified definition of the `\cventry`
- In preamble move the package `hyperref` on the end of the loaded packages and remove package `url` since it is part pf the `\hyperref`

A complete MWE with correct way to changing font sizes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}
% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch} % font
\pagestyle{empty} % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram} % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx} % figures
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage{multicol} % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist} % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\upshape\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\newcommand{\cventry}[3]{% modified, considered is my answer to your previous 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{1cm}} r @{}}
\bfseries #1    & #2    \\
#3              &       \\
\end{tabularx}\par\vspace*{1.5mm}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newenvironment{Objective}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} Objective}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
\end{figure}
    \footnotesize
    \href{https://www.google.be/}{xxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyy} \\
    \scriptsize
    xyyyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com        \\
    +xx yyy xx xx xx                \\
    xx years                        \\
    \SmallSep
    WallStreet 10                   \\
    New York                        \\
    USA                             \\
    \Sep
    \footnotesize
    \textbf{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{Languages}}\hfill~ \\ % <----
    \scriptsize
     \begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item   Spanish
    \item   English
    \item   Frenc\\ \tiny(Elementary proficiency)
    \end{compactitem}
\end{flushright}\vfill\normalsize
\framebreak

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
\end{AboutMe}
% Experience
\section{Experience}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}

\section{Education}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2020}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--2019}{school}
\cventry{master 1}{2017--Present}{school}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello this is great! I changed it to: \textbf{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{Languages}}\hfill~ \\
But I was wondering, is it possible to move the Languages title + the 3 bullet points below to the same indent as the xxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy name?

Comment: hm, as far as I can see on this way it is used in code ...  now I add some explanation what I did with your MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think there is a misunderstanding about the indentation I'm trying to achieve: take a look at both pictures here: This is what I currently get: https://i.ibb.co/st6T1SY/situation-cp.png but ideally I would want some extra padding on the left like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z46Ut.png

Is it pssible to put it in some kind of div (block of code) and add some padding on the left ?

Comment: great thanks for the info!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understood you. The second line is simple wider than the the first one, so the first line look as intended. Its seems that you need to reconsider concept of the your document design. It might help to use `minipage` in the left column. Ask new question :-)

Comment: Note, text below figure is unclear. Regarding text writed in `\href` and line below it,  what you like to show?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two main issues here:

1. to move the text language to the left use the command

   ```
   \textbf{\color{RoyalBlue}{Languages}}\hfill~ \\% <==================
   ```
2. To get more space to be able to print the very long email in one line without reaching over the margins just make the first column in your CV bigger with the following code:

   ```
   \newflowframe{0.25\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left] % <=========== .2 -> .25
       \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
       \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.25\textwidth} % <========================= .2 -> .25
       \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
   ```
3. There are more issues in your code, for example an `\RequirePackage` instead correct `\usepackage` or you are using commands `\scriptsize` wrong, they are switches, that means after calling `\scriptsize` stays changed until you use a new command to change the fontsize like `\footnotesize` or others. Or you use a group like `{\scriptsize ...}`, then the fontsize is only used for the text inside the `{...}`. Please note that I used option `showframe` for `geometry` to visualize the typing area and margings. Now you can check if your email goes into the left margin or not. For your real document comment this option please! And please play with the value for `-5cm` to get  a proper space between image and following personal informations in command

   ```
   \vspace{-5cm} % <=================================================== -7cm -> -5cm
   ```

Please see the following corrected MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch} % font
\pagestyle{empty} % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram} % column layout
\usepackage[%
  top=1cm,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx} % figures
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color
\usepackage{multicol} % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist} % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{titlesec} % <===============================================

\usepackage{url} % URLs
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\upshape\color{RoyalBlue}}{}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\newcommand{\cventry}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{\hspace{0.5cm}}r@{}}%@{\extracolsep{1cm}}
  {\bfseries #1} & {#2} \\%
  {#3} &\\%
  \end{tabularx}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.25\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left] % <=========== .2 -> .25
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.25\textwidth} % <========================= .2 -> .25
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newenvironment{Objective}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} Objective}}
    {\SmallSep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
    \vspace{-5cm} % <=================================================== -7cm -> -5cm
\end{figure}
    \footnotesize % <===================================================
    \href{https://www.google.be/}{xxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyy} \\
    \scriptsize % <=====================================================
    xyyyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com  \\
    +xx yyy xx xx xx \\
    xx years \\
    \SmallSep
    WallStreet 10  \\
    New York \\ 
    USA \\
    \Sep
    \textbf{\color{RoyalBlue}{Languages}}\hfill~ \\% <==================
    \begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Spanish
    \item English
    \item French \\ \tiny (Elementary proficiency)
    \end{compactitem}
    \hfill
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

and see its result:

[image: pdf result]